# Why grayed var:colon is added in Java editor in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ 2016.3.2
Build #IC-163.10154.41 
Built on Dec.21, 2016

grayed var:colon is automatically added in front of argument in a caller method in Java editor as you see below ( greyed a: b: are added). 
Why is this happening? I don't want to see these grayed ones. 
How to set it up in config.? (I guess this is occurring in the latest version of IntelliJ since I'm using older version in another machine without this problem.)

[image]

Comment: please give some feedback if my answer was useful. That's the way stack overflow works :-)

Answer (score 5):

The grey names followed by the colon are the parameter names from the method definition.

If you don't want them, right click on a grey word and select `Disable Parameter Name Hints`.

It's not a bug, it's a feature ;-)

[image]

If you want to reactivate it, go to `Settings` --> `Editor` --> `General` --> `Appearance` --> Option `Show parameter name hints`

Comment: +1 for this answer.  So hard to find when you don't even know what it is (parameter hints!).  I kept left clicking the damn thing, which didn't do anything.  Of course, I forgot to try right-click.